# Why does CSS.escape not escape with \\ as required?

Tags: javascript, html, css

If I have an element with ID: `elementid(2)` and want to select it using `document.querySelector`:

```
document.querySelector('#elementid(2)');      ---------- DOES NOT WORK 
document.querySelector('#elementid\\(2\\)');  ---------- WORKS!
document.querySelector(CSS.escape('#elementid(2)'));  -- DOES NOT WORK
```

Why does `CSS.escape` not escape with `\\` as required and instead with `\`? Is there a clean way that actually does this correctly without needing frameworks?

Comment: Re edit: "document.querySelector('#' + CSS.escape('elementid(2)'));  -- DOES NOT WORK" — It does work.

Comment: You're right. I reverted the edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CSS.escape` escapes **all** characters with special meaning in CSS.

Given your input of `#elementid(2)` the output is `\#elementid\(2\)`.

It has escaped the `#` as well as the characters you intended to escape.

Proper use of it would be something like:

```js
const id = 'elementid(2)';
const CSS_safe_id = CSS.escape(id);
const selector = `#${CSS_safe_id}`;
const element = document.querySelector(selector);
console.log(element.textContent);
```

```html
<div id="elementid(2)">Hello, world</div>
```

Of course, that could be combined into a one-liner, but that would be less clear.

```
const element = document.querySelector(`#${CSS.escape('elementid(2)')}`);
```

---

> Why does CSS.escape not escape with \ as required and instead with \?

That isn't a problem, but it is because the `\` character itself needs to be escaped in *string literal syntax*.

The output of `CSS.escape` is a string in memory, not a string literal in source code.

Comment: Sorry about the typo in the question. `document.querySelector('#' + CSS.escape('elementid(2)'));` would still not work. It seems to be because two `\\` are needed to escape and not one `\`.

Comment: @srrvnn — You're wrong. See the last paragraph in the answer (and the live demo)

Comment: Apologies, let me check in a jsfiddle.

Comment: Sorry Quentin, you were right. This works. https://jsfiddle.net/9oe16xuz/. The difference in \\s seem to be string literal vs string in memory. Thank you.